# change smp_affinity from linux device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

If I examine the

```
cat /proc/interrupts
```

command, all the IRQs are listed under cpu0 in SMP system.
I can change the smp_affinity mask to tag the IRQ to particular CPU using following command.

```
 echo "4" > /proc/irq/230/smp_affinity
```

Above command sets the affinity mask of the interrupt 230 to CPU 2.

I would like achieve same from linux kernel module. How can I do this?
I see create_proc_entry method which allows to create new proc entry.
Is there any method which we can use to write existing proc entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a kernel module you can just call the kernel API function irq_set_affinity(...) directly. No need to go through /proc. See: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/manage.c#L189

Comment: Thanks, smp_affinity was an example. In general, I was looking for how to overwrite existing proc file system.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense. /proc is a virtual file system 0 it's an interface the kernel exposes to user space. In a kernel module you can just call the underlying kernel API directly.