# How to set smp_affinity from linux kernel module in linux 3.0+

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

An answer to this question was posted here:
[change smp_affinity from linux device driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858487/change-smp-affinity-from-linux-device-driver)

But the answer suggests that, we use `irq_set_affinity()`. However, this is not an 'exported' symbol. I tried `irq_set_affinity_hint()`, but it doesn't seem to help, as the result is not guaranteed.

What is the correct 'exported' kernel API to use to set the smp_affinity from a kernel module?

Comment: From kernel code you can see that both `irq_set_affinity()` and `irq_set_affinity_hint()` are calling `__irq_set_affinity()` with the same arguments provided. So you should be fine with `irq_set_affinity_hint()`, as it is exported symbol and can be used in kernel module. I can't really understand why you think that `the result is not guaranteed` in case of `irq_set_affinity_hint()`?

Comment: I am on linux 3.4, here is what irq_set_affinity_hint() looks like, it is not calling __irq_set_affinity().                                                                                                          195int irq_set_affinity_hint(unsigned int irq, const struct cpumask *m)
196{
197 unsigned long flags;
198 struct irq_desc *desc = irq_get_desc_lock(irq, &flags, IRQ_GET_DESC_CHECK_GLOBAL);
199
200 if (!desc)
201  return -EINVAL;
202 desc->affinity_hint = m;
203 irq_put_desc_unlock(desc, flags);
204 return 0;
205}
206EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(irq_set_affinity_hint);

Comment: Here is a URL, sorry for the jumbled up code.  http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/manage.c?v=3.9#L196

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right, I wasn't aware of your kernel version. `__irq_set_affinity()` call was added to `irq_set_affinity_hint()` in [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e2e64a932556cdfae455497dbe94a8db151fc9fa) commit. Commit message is pretty explanatory. You will probably need to cherry-pick that change or move to newer kernel that already has it, as `irq_set_affinity_hint()` seems the only relevant exported function.